# Cloth simulation not working on cycles(render)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics, cloth-simulation

POST UPDATED

In order to animate a mop I followed this tutorial to add animation to hair https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ek0QphhYmI, the hair seems fine in all view modes except in the render where it goes crazy. When I render the same frame twice or more sometimes it renders it normal but most of the times goes crazy https://imgur.com/JogjwFF.

I don't know if is the parenting https://imgur.com/ZGTB91H, or is it the frames of the animation (currently from 70-150).

Baking animation doesnt solve it, and deleting the cube that has the cloth physic still results in the same mistake, prob has to do with the way i did the hair like the video. IDK i would love some help

My blend file (https://we.tl/t-l7uqRa7qWB)

Comment: did you bake the cloth animation before? if that doesn't help, i would recommend providing your blend file

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: @Chris Updated!!! Thanks

Comment: @Chris tried baking animation, hairs still fly in some frames, dont undertand the reason